# How to get normal Camera view in Surfaceview android?

Tags: android, camera, surfaceview

Right now, i am doing an sample app where i have to use camera in surfaceview. I have successfully set the camera in surfaceview but i can't get the normal camera view in it, width and height gets changed. Below is my code, i am pleased to get any ideas from anyone.

Camera class:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.camera);
            cameraObject = isCameraAvailiable();
    showCamera = new ShowCamera(this, cameraObject);
    preview.addView(showCamera);
            takePhotoButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        cameraObject.takePicture(null, null, capturedIt);
        cameraObject.stopPreview();
        preview.removeView(showCamera);
        cameraObject.release();
        cameraObject = Camera.open();
        showCamera = new ShowCamera(Photo.this, cameraObject);

        preview.addView(showCamera);
        }
    });
}
```

SurfaceHolder class:

```
public class ShowCamera extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

private SurfaceHolder holdMe;
private Camera theCamera;

public ShowCamera(Context context, Camera camera) {
    super(context);
    theCamera = camera;
    holdMe = getHolder();
    holdMe.addCallback(this);
}

public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
        int height) {
    theCamera.stopPreview();
    theCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
    camWidth = width;
    camHeight = height;
    theCamera.startPreview();
    initPreview(width, height);
}

private void initPreview(int width, int height) {
    // Log.i(TAG, "initPreview()starts");

    if (theCamera != null) {
        try {
             Camera.Parameters param;
             param = camera.getParameters();
             param.setPreviewSize(176, 144);
             camera.setParameters(param);
            theCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holdMe);
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            Log.e("PreviewDemo-surfaceCallback",
                    "Exception in setPreviewDisplay()", t);
        }
    }

    // Log.i(TAG, "initPreview() ends");
}

@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    try {
        theCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
        theCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holdme);
        theCamera.startPreview();
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }
}

public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder arg0) {
    this.getHolder().removeCallback(this);
    theCamera.stopPreview();
    theCamera.release();
}
```

}

Framelayout.xml

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/preview1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true">

</FrameLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: In your **Camera** class, there is a  member **preview**. How is it defined and initialized?

Comment: Above code is the one, u can see in it.

Comment: No, I only see statements like `preview.addView()` or `preview.removeView()`, but not one like `preview - new Preview(width, height);`.

Comment: ya i got it now, after setting the camera parameters its working.

Comment: but still not able to get the extact camera view. should i change the camera parameter height and width.

Comment: Please explain where and how you initialize **preview** field.

Comment: i have initialized preview in framelayout (private static FrameLayout preview;).

Answer (score 0):

If you want your to display the camera without distortion, you should override `layout_height` for **preview** frame. If you know that the camera supports 176x144 preview size, and this is what you really want to use, then simply set the layout parameters of **preview**,

```
showCamera = new ShowCamera(this, cameraObject);

ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp = preview.getLayoutParams();
lp.width = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();
//*** no, this is wrong!! ***   lp.height = lp.width*144/176;
lp.height = lp.width*176/144; // that's correct for Camera.setDisplayOrientation(90) !!
preview.setLayoutParams(lp);

preview.addView(showCamera);
```

Comment: i had gone with above solution on setting width and height but it remains the same.

Comment: if i set the height of the cameraview to 200dp it shows the image in strech how could i get the normal image

Comment: You should change the layout of preview before you call `addView(showCamera)`. However, if you don't care about different screen sizes, simply calculate screen width*144/176 and set this as layout_height in your XML. You should use **px** and not **dp**, or use the relevant scaling factor. If your screenshot is 1:1, and the screen width is really **200px**, then the height should be set to **163px**

Comment: let me try it and know for u

Comment: can you give any sample programs or links?

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong. I have fixed the answer. I overlooked the display orientation of 90°. The 4 lines in `onCreate()` are enough. Note, with this setup you the camera rectangle does not look as on your screenshot: it almost fills the screen vertically. If you want to crop the camera preview to look more like on your sketch, you can simply overlay the lower part of the screen.

Comment: is there anythere way to get normal camera view without being stretched and with same framelayout width and height.

Comment: So, you have 3 options: use landscape layout; fill almost all screen as I show above; or, overlay the preview with a non-transparent view to "clip" the preview.