# Camera Preview Size too Large

Tags: android, android-layout, android-camera

In my applciation I want to show a camera preview in a `FrameLayout` on top of my layout.
Here is what I want to achieve:

```
+---------------+
| Camera Prev.  |
|               |
+---------------+
|               |
|               |
+---------------+
|               |
|               |
+---------------+
```

The screen is seperated into 3 areas and on the top most area I want to see the camera preview.
The preview should have the right aspect ratio, so nothing gets stretched. At least the height should be fixed. The width doesn't have to match the whole screen size width.

Here is my Layout.xml:

```
  <!--CAMERA PREVIEW-->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/camera_preview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"/>

    <!--ANTOTHER SURFACE VIEW-->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/control_layer"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="#FF000000"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"/>

    <!--CONTROLS AND BUTTONS-->
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonGraphGLStart"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#FF00FF00"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:text="Start"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

This layout works and I see three areas with equal height. Now on the first area I want to show the camera preview. Below is my Code:

```
public class GraphGLFragment extends Fragment {

    private Camera mCamera;
    private CameraPreview mPreview;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_graphgl, null);
        mCamera = getCameraInstance();
        mPreview = new CameraPreview(this.getActivity(), mCamera);
        FrameLayout frameLayout = (FrameLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.camera_preview);
        frameLayout.addView(mPreview);
        return view;
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.graph_video_menu, menu);
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    }

    /**
     * A safe way to get an instance of the Camera object.
     */
    public static Camera getCameraInstance() {
        Camera c = null;
        try {
            c = Camera.open();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Camera is not available (in use or does not exist)
        }
        return c; // returns null if camera is unavailable
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
    }


    public class CameraPreview extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

        private static final String TAG = "CameraPreview";

        private Context mContext;
        private SurfaceHolder mHolder;
        private Camera mCamera;
        private List<Camera.Size> mSupportedPreviewSizes;
        private Camera.Size mPreviewSize;

        public CameraPreview(Context context, Camera camera) {
            super(context);
            mContext = context;
            mCamera = camera;

            // supported preview sizes
            mSupportedPreviewSizes = mCamera.getParameters().getSupportedPreviewSizes();
            for(Camera.Size str: mSupportedPreviewSizes)
                Log.e(TAG, str.width + "/" + str.height);

            // Install a SurfaceHolder.Callback so we get notified when the
            // underlying surface is created and destroyed.
            mHolder = getHolder();
            mHolder.addCallback(this);
            // deprecated setting, but required on Android versions prior to 3.0
            mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
        }

        public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            // empty. surfaceChanged will take care of stuff
        }

        public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            // empty. Take care of releasing the Camera preview in your activity.
        }

        public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h) {
            Log.e(TAG, "surfaceChanged => w=" + w + ", h=" + h);
            // If your preview can change or rotate, take care of those events here.
            // Make sure to stop the preview before resizing or reformatting it.
            if (mHolder.getSurface() == null){
                // preview surface does not exist
                return;
            }

            // stop preview before making changes
            try {
                mCamera.stopPreview();
            } catch (Exception e){
                // ignore: tried to stop a non-existent preview
            }

            // set preview size and make any resize, rotate or reformatting changes here
            // start preview with new settings
            try {
                Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
                parameters.setPreviewSize(mPreviewSize.width, mPreviewSize.height);
                mCamera.setParameters(parameters);
                mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
                mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder);
                mCamera.startPreview();

            } catch (Exception e){
                Log.d(TAG, "Error starting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
            final int width = resolveSize(getSuggestedMinimumWidth(), widthMeasureSpec);
            final int height = resolveSize(getSuggestedMinimumHeight(), heightMeasureSpec);

            if (mSupportedPreviewSizes != null) {
                mPreviewSize = getOptimalPreviewSize(mSupportedPreviewSizes, width, height);
            }

            float ratio;
            if(mPreviewSize.height >= mPreviewSize.width)
                ratio = (float) mPreviewSize.height / (float) mPreviewSize.width;
            else
                ratio = (float) mPreviewSize.width / (float) mPreviewSize.height;

            // One of these methods should be used, second method squishes preview slightly
            setMeasuredDimension(width, (int) (width * ratio));
//        setMeasuredDimension((int) (width * ratio), height);
        }

        private Camera.Size getOptimalPreviewSize(List<Camera.Size> sizes, int w, int h) {
            final double ASPECT_TOLERANCE = 0.1;
            double targetRatio = (double) h / w;

            if (sizes == null)
                return null;

            Camera.Size optimalSize = null;
            double minDiff = Double.MAX_VALUE;

            int targetHeight = h;

            for (Camera.Size size : sizes) {
                double ratio = (double) size.height / size.width;
                if (Math.abs(ratio - targetRatio) > ASPECT_TOLERANCE)
                    continue;

                if (Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight) < minDiff) {
                    optimalSize = size;
                    minDiff = Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight);
                }
            }
            if (optimalSize == null) {
                minDiff = Double.MAX_VALUE;
                for (Camera.Size size : sizes) {
                    if (Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight) < minDiff) {
                        optimalSize = size;
                        minDiff = Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight);
                    }
                }
            }
            Log.d(TAG,optimalSize.width + " "+ optimalSize.height + "-----");
            return optimalSize;
        }
    }
}
```

There is no error, and the aspect ratio is also correct (no stretched image), however the preview is too large. I do not see the whole preview. I guess that the preview size is not calculated correctly according to the available size of the hosting camer_preview `FrameLayout`
Anybody knows what's the problem here?

In `surfaceCHanged()` the surface has w = 1536 and h= 2730 which is way too big...

Answer (score 0):

Your device is in Portrait mode, and the preview is rotated accordingly. To keep the aspect ratio, you must have the surface higher than wider

```
----------
|        |  
|        |  
|        |  
|        |  
|        |  
|        |  
|        |  
----------
```

To achieve the result:

```
----------
|        |  
|        |  
|XXXXXXXX|  
|XXXXXXXX|  
|XXXXXXXX|  
|XXXXXXXX|  
|XXXXXXXX|  
----------
```

you should **crop** the picture. The easiest way is to display the other parts of your UI on top of the surface. Alternatively, you can use SurfaceTexture and manipulate the OpenGL transform to crop the image.

Few days ago, I answered a similar question: [How to get normal Camera view in Surfaceview android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26135405/how-to-get-normal-camera-view-in-surfaceview-android).

Comment: Hi, I don't want to crop the image. But I want to see the full preview in the top area with correct ratio. It's ok if the preview width doesnt match the width of the area.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show the full preview (i.e. no cropping), but can sacrifice the width of the preview surface (to keep the aspect ratio), change the code in `onMeasure()`:

```
setMeasuredDimension((int)(height/ratio), height);
setLayoutParams(new Frameayout.LayoutParams((int)(height/ratio), height, Gravity.CENTER));
```

Here is the expected layout:

```
----------
|XX    XX|  
|XX    XX|  
|XX    XX|  
|XXXXXXXX|  
|XXXXXXXX|  
|XXXXXXXX|  
|XXXXXXXX|  
----------
```

Comment: So, it is NOT possible to view a landscape preview (with full preview, just smaller) when the device is in portrait mode? is this right?

Comment: No, it's not possible because the camera sensor is physically layed out this way. The pixel layout can be rotated programmatically, what we achieve with `Camera.setDisplayOrientation(90)`, but this does not rotate the sensor itself.